# How to check whether user has already once signed in using Google+API in my web application?

Tags: php

I am trying to use Google+API &PHP for login in my web application.whether I need to store the data when they sign in and check the database everytime they login??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yes,Add authprovider field in your table.
When any user login with google at first time then store google in your database.
After than when user Login again then use query like this:

$query = "SELECT authprovider,email FROM tbl_users WHERE authprovider='$authprovider' AND email='$email'";
$exe = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$check = mysqli_num_rows($exe);
if($check == 1){
  //already registered
}
else{
 //new register
}
```